# C# MVC 5 Custom controller class to inherit from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inheritance, controller

I have a repository that I want to use on all of my pages.

By default, all of MVC controllers inherit from `Controller` class. I have created `CustomBaseController` class where I have defined field for my `Repository` and I have instantiated repo with context in `CustomBaseController` constructor.

How ever, when I want to create a new controller e.g. `HomeController` that inherits from `CustomBaseController`, my repository field (db) is not visible.

Here is example from my new `CustomBaseController` :

```
public class CustomBaseController : Controller {
    private IRepository db; // <-- defined
    public CustomController() {
        // here it is initialized
        db = new DbRepository(new ApplicationDBContext());
    }
}
```

And also from my `HomeController` :

```
public class ProgramController : CustomBaseController
{
    // GET: Program
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // db is not accessible here for some reason, 
        // like it wasn't inherited from CustomBaseController
        var user = db.getUserByID(1);
        return List(user);
    }
...
```

Comment: So make it protected.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `IRepository` field `protected` instead of `private` and it will be visible in child classes.

Comment: yes, just noticed that -.-, this was a case of brain fart from my end

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem. I made my repo variable private by accident